# VBA - aliases in listbox in a userform

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a userform set up that sends an e-mail. There's a listbox with a list of e-mail addresses that map to the .To property. Instead of having the e-mail addresses in the listbox, I'd like to have people's names shown that would then map to their e-mail address. How could I do that?

Here's my code that populates the listbox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ToBox
    .AddItem "john@business.com"
    .AddItem "bill@business.com"
    .AddItem "mary@business.com"
    .AddItem "adam@business.com"
    .AddItem "jane@business.com"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a 2D array. Col1 =Names, Col2 = Email address and then use that

Comment: Where do you get the names from? What's the email server? Exchange?

Comment: They are from an Exchange server. But some of the addresses added later might be outside of that.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Could you be a little more specific? I'm not sure how to do that in a case like this.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You want the names to auto resolve to email address in the Exchange Server? Or do you have both piece of Information (the name and the email) and you want to do some kind of lookup?

Comment: I have both pieces, but I don't want the e-mail address to show in the listbox. I only want the person's name to show. There will only be around 15 addresses.

Comment: So I didn't misunderstand. :D One moment. posting a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but I came up with this as a way to do what I wanted. In the Sub to actually send the e-mail, I did this. It takes the value of the ComboBox and goes through an If routine to get the e-mail address.

```
If Questions.ToBox.Value = "John" Then
    .To = "john@business.com"
    End If
If Questions.ToBox.Value = "Bill" Then
    .To = "bill@business.com"
    End If
If Questions.ToBox.Value = "Mary" Then
    .To = "mary@business.com"
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim EmailArray(1 To 15, 1 To 15) As String
Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Set your 15 names and email address here
    EmailArray(1, 1) = "Siddharth Rout": EmailArray(1, 2) = "Blah@Siddharthrout.Com"
    EmailArray(2, 1) = "Name1 Here": EmailArray(2, 2) = "Email1 Here"
    EmailArray(3, 1) = "Name2 Here": EmailArray(3, 2) = "Email2 Here"
    '
    ' And so on..
    '
    EmailArray(15, 1) = "Name15 Here": EmailArray(15, 2) = "Email15 Here"

    '~~> Add the names from Col 1 to listbox
    For i = 1 To 15
        ToBox.AddItem EmailArray(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub

'~~> Match the value from listbox with array and retrieve the
'~~> corresponding column value
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ToBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        For i = 1 To 15
            If ToBox.Value = EmailArray(i, 1) Then
                MsgBox "the name you selected is " & EmailArray(i, 1) & _
                " and the email address is " & EmailArray(i, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error: "Sub or Function not defined."

Comment: @Robby specify `Option Explicit`, you have a typo.

Comment: @Robby: The above code is tried and tested :) Which line is giving you the error>

Comment: It's highlighting this part "EmailArray(1, 1) ="

Comment: Did you declare `Dim EmailArray(1 To 15, 1 To 15) As String` at the top like I have done it? :)

Comment: I didn't at the VERY top. That took care of that problem. But now I'm trying to combine what I had in CommandButton1_Click with what you gave. This is what I had before: 'ToBox = Questions.ToBox
'SubjectBox = Questions.SubjectBox
'BodyBox = Questions.BodyBox

Comment: @Robby: What is `Questions`,`Questions.ToBox`, `ToBox` etc etc? I do not see that in your quesiotn? Where did those come from?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. `Questions` is the name of the userform. `ToBox`, `SubjectBox`, and `BodyBox` are the names of the text boxes in the userform.

Comment: `ToBox =EmailArray(i, 2)` Is this what you are trying?

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you gave me.